# Is it possible to play simcity4 on Lubuntu?

Tags: windows

I would like to play simcity4 on lubuntu is that possible. I tried to play it pressing execute but that did not work. This came is really meant to be played on windows XP. Can some one help me. I am new at this, so if I do something wrong let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Install wine, and then install simcity4.  The winehq pages gives it a pretty good likelyhood of running:
https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=4088